# ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments ERROR

Tags: sql, oracle

I have sql sever that is using a linked server to Oracle and i am trying to sum and count some values but getting the above error.  I am trying to group it by Dept Code and Fac Code but  I am not sure what am i doing wrong here?  Please note i am pulling the data from Oracle server.
Here is what i have:

```
 SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (MYLINKEDSERVER,'SELECT LTRIM(CODE) AS FAC_CODE,
      COUNT(ACCOUNT_NO)AS ACCOUNT_NO, 
      LTRIM(DEP_CODE) AS DEP_CODE,  
       SUM(UNITS) AS TOTAL_UNITS,
       ROUND(SUM(CHARGES, 2)) AS CHARGES
       from myTable
       group by CODE, DEP_CODE ' )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is the `round()` function.  It takes two arguments, not `sum()`:

```
   ROUND(SUM(CHARGES), 2) AS CHARGES
```